# Android send dtmf to incoming call

Tags: android, dtmf, incoming-call

I'm try send DTMF codes in icoming CALL. For this i'n try use Java reflection:

```
public void initialize(){
    ClassLoader classLoader = Dtmf.class.getClassLoader();
    final Class<?> classCallManager =           classLoader.loadClass("com.android.internal.telephony.CallManager");
    Method methodGetInstance = classCallManager.getDeclaredMethod("getInstance");
    objectCallManager = methodGetInstance.invoke(null);
    methodGetState = classCallManager.getDeclaredMethod(SEND_DTMF, char.class);
}


public boolean sendDtmf(char ch) {
        boolean result = false;
        if ( methodGetState != null) {
            try {
                Object res = methodGetState.invoke(objectCallManager, 
                        new Object[]{Character.valueOf(ch)});

                if (res instanceof Boolean) {
                    result = ((Boolean) res).booleanValue(); 
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Link for source code of class CallManager : [Call Manager source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.2.2_r1/com/android/internal/telephony/CallManager.java)
But i'm always get "false" in method sendDtmf(). In debug, code is go into next:

```
 Object res = methodGetState.invoke(objectCallManager, 
                            new Object[]{Character.valueOf(ch)});
```

What wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The method is likely throwing an InvocationTargetException if your application isn't signed with the platform certificate as conventional apps cannot execute these methods (and will not be granted the required platform permissions to do so).

In short: the method is returning false because you're catching (and ignoring) the exception.

There's an open issue ([#1428](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=1428)) on the Android issue tracker for sending DTMF tones as it presently isn't possible.